# Change Image Size with Javascript (replicate)

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Okay so i have been looking at this for over a week and can not figure it out.  Basically here is an example of the end result i posted earlier:

[Previous Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405792/change-image-size-on-javascript-event)

Their suggestions did not work.  The javascript is changing the header css when you click on the buttons to the top right.  Here is a Demo: [DEMO of JAVASCRIPT CHANGE](http://yakko.cs.wmich.edu/~brain/SAS/)

I'm Trying to duplicate this action with the image, but i however do not know javascript that well and am not too sure what i am reading when i look at the javascript file.  I either would like someone to help me read this javascript so i can edit it myself or help me find a solution.

Here is the Javascript: [Script.JS](http://pastebin.com/wauW66ZS)

Here is the relevant HTML that i have done so far:

```
body >
<div id="gspinner" class="spinner"></div>
<div id="glob">
<header>
    <div class="inner">


    <a href="#!/home"><h5><img src="images/logo_large.png" /></h5></a>
            <!--<a href="#!/home"><img src="logo-large.png" id="img-             logo" alt="" /></a>
            <!--<a  href="#!/home"></></a>-->

        <nav>
            <ul>

                <li class="li-2"><a href="#!/about"><span class="lbl">About Us</span><span class="ico -def"></span><span class="ico -hvr"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#!/history">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/mission">Mission Statement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/solutions">Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/distribution">Distribution Area</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/logo">SAS Logo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="li-1"><a href="#!/events"><span class="lbl">Events</span><span class="ico -def"></span><span class="ico -hvr"></span></a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#!/tradeshow">Trade Show</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/awesomeachievers">Awesome Achievers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/whatshappening">What's Happening</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li class="li-3"><a href="#!/technology"><span class="lbl">Technology</span><span class="ico -def"></span><span class="ico -hvr"></span></a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#!/nexgen">NexGen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/synergy">Synergy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/edi">EDI</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="li-4"><a href="#!/marketing"><span class="lbl">Marketing</span><span class="ico -def"></span><span class="ico -hvr"></span></a></li>
                <li class="li-5"><a href="#!/sales"><span class="lbl">Sales</span><span class="ico -def"></span><span class="ico -hvr"></span></a></li>
                <li class="li-6"><a href="#!/mail"><span class="lbl">Employment</span><span class="ico -def"></span><span class="ico -hvr"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

And here is the CSS: [Style.css](http://pastebin.com/FEqsVFpJ)

ANY help would be greatly appreciated and will get "points" for it, i have been working on this for over a week with no help, but i have decided i should reach out for help.

THANKS!

Comment: Not a Javascript solution, but I managed to achieve what you want using CSS; just add `height: 40%` to your logo image and it should scale with the header (note that you'll probably need to use a higher-quality version of the logo)...

Comment: does it change when you click on the buttons to the top right like the demo? Take a look at the demo to see what i mean, the header is the black part that changes size. I got it to fit, thats not the issue, the issue is getting it to change WITH the header

Comment: Yes, it scales up and down as the header grows/shrinks. Try it and see - you can use your browser's developer tools to try it without having to modify the code.

Comment: *twitch* *twitch*....it works...thanks...i feel like the biggest dumbass in the world right now...

Comment: Respond as an answer please so i can mark you for getting it right

Comment: No problem. It's easy to overthink these things sometime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Javascript solution, but I managed to achieve what you want using CSS; just add 'height: 40%' to your logo image and it should scale with the header (note that you'll probably need to use a higher-quality version of the logo), as the current one gets a bit pixellated when it grows.

Comment: all i want to do right now is break my keyboard, I didn't know the javascript from the header would take over because its in the header css.  It makes sense now, but as i said i bought this template and the guy who made it didn't comment AT ALL! So I had to go through every piece of code and figure out WTF he was doing